# Can I reuse decorators?

Tags: php, mysql, oop, design-patterns, decorator

Can I reuse **decorators**?

I have a `ClientDecorator` to decorate an entity that has a reference of a client, this decorator gets the client on database on call **getClient** (before it gets decorated, this method returns the clientId, after being decorated, it returns an instance of **Client**).

Okay, but, I've some other entities that can be decorated with the same decorator, for example, I have another table named `questions`, this table has a reference pointing to a client that has asked a question, and I have another table named `schedules`, that has a reference of a client.

By the way, I can decorate `question` and `schedule` with `ClientDecorator`.

But, I have an `QuestionDecorator` too; this guy decorates an `Answer`, etc.

How I can do this abstraction, so I can reuse decorators whenever I want?

I've tried to create `ClientDecorable`, `QuestionDecorable` interfaces, but have made no progress.

Comment: You need to define interfaces. Just like you wrote. Your decorator will only accept components implementing defined interfaces. This is the way to go. Post the code you have.

Comment: Gimme an example @busypeoples

Comment: Have you noticed that `*Decorator` is a bad name for a decorator? You should give things descriptive names... It's hard to say what you can or cannot do if we don't know which functionalities your decorator will change...

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos, in this specific case, it was decorating an entity, eg: Question, ->getClient ... and it return the client id, true ? when decorated, return instance of corresponding client.

Comment: But what do your decorators change?

Comment: Behavior of method getClient, when i do FETCH_CLASS, PDO fills the `$client` property and i want to when i apply decorator, change the behavior of method ->getClient to return instance of Client (by searching for it on database) instead of client-id (PDO-Fetched)

Answer (score 0):

You can always instance the decorator class passing parameters to the constructor that will tell it how it should behave or what class it should impersonate. You don't really have to declare your decorator as an extension of another class.

PHP classes support [magic methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php) that make it possible to forward calls to the class your object is impersonating, just as if it was extending it with `extends`.

For instance:

```
class Client
{
    public function getId() { return 123; }
}

class Decorator
{
    private $instance = null;

    public function __construct($class)
    {
        $this->instance = new $class();
    }

    public function __call($method, $params) // magic method
    {
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->instance, $method), $params);
    }
}

$object = Decorator('Client');
echo $object->getId(); // 123
```

The magic method `__call()` will be invoked when you try to access a method that doesn't belong to the class `Decorator`. The same can be done with properties by using the magic methods `__get()` and `__set()`.

Comment: This isn't a ugly way ? theoretically it's simple, eg: Client, Payment, Log ... so: Log could be decorated with Client, Payment could be decorated with Client and Log ... get the idea ? i can't see this in code :(

Comment: Not at all. I just wrote an exemple to give you an idea.

Comment: But of course the classes you are willing to extend must have methods in common. If they are completely different the code of your Decorator won't even make sense to it.

Comment: Ye, i think you're right ... even the decorator pattern must be specific, something that needs to be decorated, and it should be.

Doesn't really make sense if i try to reuse these decorators inside other decorators, something like: `$x = new ClientDecorator(new LogDecorator(new ConcretePayment()));`

If you see, all involved objects has an type of association, but: client decorate log that decorates payment, but when payment gets decorated by client ? never, never in a reusable way, i think.

Comment: Looks like you are overusing decorators, perhaps you should try a different approach.

Comment: Decorators should decorate specific things, eg: Payment, Payment could be decorated by Client and by Log, but when i have another entity that can be decorated with Log, there's an error ... in my concept ... as i said: i must have PaymentLogDecorator, PaymentClientDecorator.

Answer (score 0):

That's a really tricky problem. I could find a solution, but it is kind of McGiver style... Works for PHP 5.4+ (yes, traits).

```
<?php
interface Decorable
{

    public function getTarget();

}


interface ClientDecorable extends Decorable
{

    public function getClient();

}


interface LogDecorable extends Decorable
{

    public function getLog();

}

abstract class AbstractDecorator implements Decorable 
{

    private $target;

    public function __construct(ClientDecorable $target)
    {
        $this->target = $target;
    }

    public function getTarget()
    {
        // I'll be able to access the leaf node of my decorator single way 'tree'
        return $this->target->getTarget();
    }

    public function __call($method, $args) {

        $reflected = new ReflectionClass($this->target);
        if ($reflected->hasMethod($method)) {
            return call_user_func_array([$this->target, $method], $args);
        }
    }

}

class ClientDecorator extends AbstractDecorator implements ClientDecorable
{
    public function __construct(Decorable $target) {
        if (! $target->getTarget() instanceof ClientDecorable) {
            throw new Exception('Must be an instance de ClientDecorable');
        }
        parent::__construct($target);
    }
    public function getClient()
    {
        return new Client($this->getTarget()->getClient());
    }

}

class LogDecorator extends AbstractDecorator implements LogDecorable
{
    public function __construct(Decorable $target) {
        if (! $target->getTarget() instanceof LogDecorable) {
            throw new Exception('Must be an instance de LogDecorable');
        }
        parent::__construct($target);
    }

    public function getLog()
    {
        return new Log($this->getTarget()->getLog());
    }

}

abstract class AbstractTarget implements Decorable
{
    // this does the trick
    public function getTarget() { return $this; }
}

trait ClientDecorableTrait {
    public function getClient()
    {
        return $this->client;
    }
}

trait LogDecorableTrait {
    public function getLog()
    {
        return $this->log;
    }
}



class Payment extends AbstractTarget implements ClientDecorable, LogDecorable
{
    use ClientDecorableTrait;
    use LogDecorableTrait;

    private $client = 1;
    private $log = 101;
}

class Sale extends AbstractTarget implements ClientDecorable
{
    use ClientDecorableTrait;

    private $client = 2;

}

class Client
{

    // ...

}


class Log
{

    // ...

}

$sale = new Sale();
var_dump($sale->getClient());
$saleDec = new ClientDecorator($sale);
var_dump($saleDec->getClient());

$payment = new Payment();
var_dump($payment->getClient());
$paymentDec = new ClientDecorator($payment);
var_dump($paymentDec->getClient());

var_dump($paymentDec->getLog());
$paymentDecTwice = new LogDecorator($paymentDec);
var_dump($paymentDecTwice->getLog());

$saleDecTwice = new LogDecorator($saleDec); // will throw an exception
```

This is just a skeleton, a real world implementation must be tricky. I think you'd better keep your decorators separated...